# How to append a string to another column depending on the value of string without overriding previous data due regex not extracting all characters

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

When I extracted the alphabetical characters it didn't extract everything. My logic was to use the lambda apply function as a next step in the data cleaning process.

```
df['desc'] = df['desc'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('', 'RADIONAVIGATION'))
```

However, there is the issue of inadvertently overriding other string values.

1.

---

```
description                                 remark              desc
METEOROLOGICAL AIDS 54A                     ['54A']         METEOROLOGICAL AIDS'
METEOROLOGICAL AIDS 54A RADIONAVIGATION     ['54A']         METEOROLOGICAL AIDS'
RADIONAVIGATION
```

'RADIONAVIGATION' String Value on the description column needs to be appended onto col['desc'] but not sure how to add this string without overriding the current values with using this code.

```
df['desc'] = df['desc'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('', 'RADIONAVIGATION'))
```

Expected output

```
description                       remark              desc
METEOROLOGICAL AIDS 54A          ['54A']         METEOROLOGICAL AIDS                                 
METEOROLOGICAL AIDS 54A RADIONAVIGATION          METEOROLOGICAL AIDS                                     RADIONAVIGATION                                               RADIONAVIGATION 
RADIONAVIGATION                                  RADIONAVIGATION
```

Comment: Please provide your example input and the matching expected output

Comment: Done! Output given above